# Whitelist params - how to allow n level nesting of self relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, strong-parameters

I've got a use case where employee hierarchies are going to be stored as strings so they can be retrieved in json. (This is a POC, so just a hack for SQLite for now).

How can I permit n level of nested objects?  In the following example `:h_data` is json coming in the request body.  Right now I'm hacking it to 3 levels of hierarchy with:

```
params.require(:hierarchy_version).permit(:name, :creator_id, :top_employee_id, :h_data => [:name, :id, :salary, :manager_id, :direct_reports => [:name, :id, :salary, :manager_id, :direct_reports => [:name, :id, :salary, :manager_id, :direct_reports]]])
```